# Can't get right letter after ciphering

Tags: javascript

I am working on this problem at CodeWars: [Vowels Back](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57cfd92c05c1864df2001563)
Usually half of my tests fail, but from what I see every fail test is because of letter 'a' since I get '\backslash' instead of 'v'. Of course, I see from my calculations why I get '\backslash', I tried to fix it with something like Math.abs(), but then I was getting 'f', not 'v'. Can someone help me fix this please? All other letter changes seem correct.

```js
function vowelBack(s){
  let output = '';
  let position;
  let newPosition;
  let newChar;

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    position = s.charCodeAt(i);
    
    if (s[i] === 'c' || s[i] === 'o') {
      newPosition = ((position - 97 - 1) % 26) + 97;  
      newChar = String.fromCharCode(newPosition);
      if (newChar === 'c' || newChar === 'o' || newChar === 'd' || newChar === 'e') {
        newChar = s[i];
      }
      output += newChar;
    } else if (s[i] === 'd') {
      newPosition = ((position - 97 - 3) % 26) + 97;  
      newChar = String.fromCharCode(newPosition);
      if (newChar === 'c' || newChar === 'o' || newChar === 'd' || newChar === 'e') {
        newChar = s[i];
      }
      output += newChar;      
    } else if (s[i] === 'e') {
      newPosition = ((position - 97 - 4) % 26) + 97;  
      newChar = String.fromCharCode(newPosition);
      if (newChar === 'c' || newChar === 'o' || newChar === 'd' || newChar === 'e') {
        newChar = s[i];
      }
      output += newChar;
    } else if (s[i] === 'a' || s[i] === 'i' || s[i] === 'u') {
      newPosition = ((position - 97 - 5) % 26) + 97;  
      newChar = String.fromCharCode(newPosition);
      if (newChar === 'c' || newChar === 'o' || newChar === 'd' || newChar === 'e') {
        newChar = s[i];
      }
      output += newChar;
    } else {
      newPosition = ((position - 97 + 9) % 26) + 97;
      newChar = String.fromCharCode(newPosition);
      if (newChar === 'c' || newChar === 'o' || newChar === 'd' || newChar === 'e') {
        newChar = s[i];
      }
      output += newChar;

    }
   }
  return output;
}

console.log(vowelBack("testcase"));
```

Comment: What line in your code is causing the problem?

Comment: It was this line: else if (s[i] === 'a' || s[i] === 'i' || s[i] === 'u') {
      newPosition = ((position - 97 - 5) % 26) + 97; 

but @koorkevani solved it already, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, `-b < (a % b) < b`, as opposed to `0 <= (a % b) < b` in mathmatical notation (so `-1 % 5 == -1`, not `4`). To ensure a positive solution, write `(((a % b) + b) % b)`.

In your situation, I would add a function:

```js
function shiftLetter(position, shift) {
    return ((((position - 97 + shift) % 26) + 26) % 26) + 97;
}
```